# Doubts about condition control statements in all Computer language

Tags: programming-languages

Could the condition of if..else..if statement overlap?I mean this way to use is recommanded or not.   [test](http://www.google.com)
eg.

```
 if condition_1

 else if condition_2
 .
 .
 .
 else
```

such as:condition_1 and condition_2 is overlapped.

Comment: That code will check if condition_1 is true first, if not it check condition_2, if not it will check condition_n until it reaches an else or no more conditions to evaluate. So if 1 is true none of the others will be executed.

Comment: I want to execute the conditon_2 but the condition_1 is the first matched because of overlap.this is my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual practice is to have the conditions be mutually exclusive. However, no language I know will test the conditions for overlap. The programmer is free to make a mess this way.

Comment: I think so. This is my confusion I have.

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of the mainstream programming languages define the order that the conditions are evaluated (in the order the appear in the code) and the first that evaluates to true is selected and none of the others are evaluated. Overlap is not a problem. There is no ambiguity and no confusion about which block of code should be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, nesting `if/else` conditions is a common and valid approach to using them.

For example:

```
if (firstcheck is true) 

       if (secondcheck is true)

           //all checks passed 

       else

          //only first check passed

else
    //no checks passed
```